# Does this method of determining what a voltmeter will read in the presence of a time-varying magnetic field give the correct answer?

Tags: voltage-measurement

In [a previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/551249/268467) I offered a method for calculating a quantitative result for what a voltmeter will read when a time-varying magnetic field may be affecting the circuit and/or leads of the voltmeter.

> A voltmeter measures the (negative of the) total emf around any loop of which it is a part, minus the voltage drop on any element in that loop that drops voltage [besides the voltmeter itself].

> If a voltmeter, together with its test leads, is connected to test points A and B in a circuit, it forms a path. This path, together with any path between A and B within the circuit, forms a closed loop... If we know the emf of that loop and all the voltage drops except that of the volt-meter, then we can calculate the voltage drop through the volt-meter. That is what the volt-meter measures. The voltmeter will display the emf of the loop minus the voltage drops of all the path segments other than the voltmeter.

Let me give a concrete example. Suppose we have the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuLExB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

nd further suppose that there is a time varying magnetic field in Region 0, but no time varying magnetic fields in Regions 1 & 2.

There are multiple loops that include VM1 and the test points A and B. Our method says that it doesn't matter which loop we choose. Let's first choose the loop that encloses only region 1. Since there is no time-varying magnetic field in region 1, there is no emf induced in the loop enclosing it. So, our method says that the voltage reading in VM1 should be equal to the voltage drop across R1.

We can calculate the voltage drop across R1 if we know the values of R1, R2 and the rate of change of magnetic flux in Region 0. The rate of change of magnetic flux in region 0 will give us the emf in the loop enclosing Region 0. Let's call that \$\mathscr{E}_0\$.  Assuming the voltmeters draw no current, the current through R1 and R2 will be

$$ I_0 = \frac{\mathscr{E}_0}{R_1+R_2} = I_{R_1} = I_{R_2}$$

So the voltage drop across the components in the loop other than the voltmeter is just the negative of the voltage drop across R1 (directional arrows in diagram oppose),  or \$-I_{R_1}R_1 = -I_0R_1\;\;\$ , so the VM1 voltmeter reading will be

$$VM1Reading = 0 - (-I_0R_1) = I_0R_1$$

Now, our method says that it doesn't matter which loop we choose as long as it includes the voltmeter and it's leads. So, let's try another loop. This time, the loop that includes both Region 1 and Region 0.

Since we have assumed that the only region with a time-varying magnetic field is Region 0, the emf around the loop enclosing Region 1 and Region 0 is equal to the the emf around the loop enclosing Region 0, which we have already calculated as  \$\mathscr{E}_0\$. The voltage drop across the components other than the voltmeter is the voltage drop across R2 this time, which is \$I_0R_2\$ . So using the loop around Regions 1 and 0, we get

$$VM1Reading = \mathscr{E}_0 - I_0R_2 $$

However, as promised, these two answers have the same value.

$$I_0R_1 = \frac{\mathscr{E}_0}{R_1+R_2}R_1 = \frac{\mathscr{E}_0(R_1 + R_2 - R_2)}{R_1+R_2}= \mathscr{E}_0 - I_0R_2 $$

Now let us consider what will VM2 will display. We can choose either the loop which encloses Region 2 alone, or the loop that encloses both Region 0 and Region 2. Let us choose the loop that encloses both regions. By our assumptions, the time varying magnetic field that is enclosed by both regions is the same as that enclosed by Region 0. So, the emf  around that loop is just \$\mathscr{E}_0\$. However, the for the voltmeter VM2 is pointing in the opposite direction, so we  will need to account for that. The resistive voltage drop in that loop is just the resistive voltage drop across R1. So, the voltage reported by VM2 is

$$-\mathscr{E}_0 + I_0R_1$$

[It may be surprising to some the voltmeters VM1 and VM2 will display different values even though both are connected to the test points A and B. However, this is consistent both with theory and experiment.]

Now, I believe that this method of calculating what a voltmeter will report when a time-varying magnetic field is affecting a circuit (and possibly the voltmeter leads) gives the correct value, while others seem to disagree.

My question is
**Is this a mathematically valid way to determine quantitatively what a voltmeter will report when a time-varying magnetic field is affecting a circuit and/or the leads of the voltmeter?**

I am not looking for answers that argue about the validity or otherwise of KVL or make other arguments, unless such arguments support an answer one way or the other about whether this method gives valid results or not.

Comment: @SredniVashtar You may wish to take a look at this question and provide an answer if you choose.

Comment: Can you explain why [this question and its various answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506590/can-two-voltmeters-connected-to-the-same-terminals-show-different-values-circui/507058#507058) have not been considered or referenced?

Comment: @AndyAka My question is not whether two voltmeters connected to the same test points can report different values. Clearly they can. My question is whether the method I used to calculate what a voltmeter reads is valid. Does that help?

Comment: @Andyaka Also, although you get the same answer as myself, you do so by a different method, i.e. modeling the circuit by adding inductors. At least one poster vehemently objects to doing so, with vague arguments against "lumping". To counter that poster, I do not employ "lumping", but simply appeal to the fact that an emf is induced in the loop.

Comment: It wasn't really a model rather than just an idea expressed as a circuit with me putting voltages on that I estimated. I just used my simulator as a schematic entry tool.

Comment: @Andyaka however, in Sredni's answer he writes extensively (although imho not convincingly) that there is something wrong with "lumping". So my question is just "does the math work, or doesn't it?" Forget about all the "lumping", and other extraneous issues.

Comment: I do not need to write another answer. This is the method I suggest to measure *or compute* voltage in my other answers on this topic, including the last one on the uniform loop: measure directly thanks to KVL working in the measurent loop; compute from measure using Faraday if the measurement loop cuts a changing magnetic flux and KVL won't work to assure that the voltmeter reading is also the voltage in the measured branch. For some reason you choose to call Faraday's law "KVL". Of course it works in general, it's even one of the four Maxwell's equations.

Comment: @SredniVashtar There are at least two versions of Faraday's law. One relates the time derivative of total magnetic flux enclosed by a loop to EMF. The other relates the time derivative of magnetic field with the E field. A law that does not refer to magnetic flux is not Faraday's Law. KVL relates EMF and IR.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Do you agree that the total emf around a loop equals the sum of the 's "I*R"s around the loop? A simple yes or no will do.

Comment: I just lumped those inductors for pure pictorial convenience. The coupling between one wire and the voltmeter wire doesn’t need to be regarded as emanating from any lump to any other lump  in particular.